# Synchronize text between Android phones

Tags: java, android, api, synchronization

We are a group of six people who are trying to create a shopping list for Android. We would like to have the shopping list synchronized between two or more Android phones.

The project is part of a project on a summer camp and the deadline is in 76 hours and we do not have time to setup a server. Does anyone know of a simple way to synchronize text between two or more Android phones (perhaps with the use of online services)?

We thought about using Google Docs (they use Lists which seem to be perfect for what we want) but we are not comfortable with the Google API and it seems to huge to learn in 76 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simple like posting/getting data from say App engine shouldn't take very long to write

A http post to update the list and a http get to get the current list